# Command and Click on same control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

When clicking on a `Button` in my `View`, I am calling a `RelayCommand` from the `ViewModel`.
However, i also want to make a Stackpanel Visible with the `Click` on this button.

I tried binding a Relaycomman and making a Click method for the button, but it didn't work.
It also seemed like a pretty ugly way of doing it, but if it worked, it wouldve kept my view and viewmodel apart.

How can i interact with my View before calling the RelayCommand, as i want to keep my View and ViewModel as seperated as possible.

Answer (score 0):

My RelayCommand did actually fire after having a Click method bound to the same control.
It seem's like it works perfectly then..

I am still open to new suggestions if there is a better way to interact with the view control.

Comment: I prefer to control the visibility of specific view controls by specific properties in the viewmodel, such as 'ShowLoginButton'. Then all the view has to to is to bind to this property using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter. Then the full application logic of what to show when is implemented by the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add a `bool` property to your ViewModel, (e.g., `IsMyPanelVisible`). The `Visibility` of your `StackPanel` is bound to this property and, in your command `Execute` method, you set the value of the property to whatever you need.

In my opininion this is the simplest and cleanest approach.